# adding 1 to textbox from a function

Tags: javascript, html

trying to add 1 or minus 1 to the value in the textbox depending on which button is clicked. cant get to work... not sure whats wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Add and Subtract Numbers</title>
 <body>
 <script>
function display(buttonclickedvalue)
{
    switch (buttonclickedvalue)
    {
        case"+"

            var number= parseInt(document.getElementById('numbertxt').value);
            number.value = number + 1;
        break;
        case"-"
            var number1= parseInt(document.getElementById('numbertxt').value);
            number1.value = number1 -1;
        break
    }

}

 </script>
 <form name="calculations">
 <input type = text id="numbertxt">
 </br>
 <input type = button value="+" onclick="display(this.value)">
 <input type = button value="-" onclick="display(this.value)">

 </form>
 </body>
 </head>
 </html>
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/un3EJ/)

Comment: Your cases are syntactically wrong.

Comment: Before anyone answers your question, could you please accept the correct answer on your previous questions (if any)? If you keep asking without coming back to mark the correct answer, people will be less willing to help you in the future.

Comment: didnt think u had to do this. it says dont say thanks or +1. il do it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you even use cases with only 2 options?

```
function display(buttonclickedvalue)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('numbertxt').value);

    if(buttonclickedvalue == '+')
    {
        value +=  1;
    }
    else
    {
        value -= 1;
    }

    document.getElementById('numbertxt').value = value
}
```

This way you only have to validate the case once, instead of twice.
(ofcourse, you have to add more validations when you want more options).

Comment: Just because there's 2 options now doesn't mean there won't be more later?

Comment: that's why i said "you have to add more validations when you want more options". I see no reason why you would use cases. I find the if-then-else structure, personally, having a better overview. Especially for beginners this might be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons that code isn't working:

1. `case` expressions end with a `:`, so the code can't be parsed successfully.
2. Your `number` and `number1` variables refer to the **number**, not the element, and so assigning to a `.value` property on them doesn't do what you want. (It does something, *very* briefly, but nothing that lasts.)

Also, it's best to always give `parseInt` its second argument, which is the radix (number base) it should use when parsing.

If you want to use `switch` for this, then:

```
function display(buttonclickedvalue)
{
    var numfield = document.getElementById('numbertxt'),
        num      = parseInt(numfield.value, 10) || 0;
    switch (buttonclickedvalue)
    {
        case "+":
            numfield.value = num + 1;
            break;
        default:
            numfield.value = num - 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

There I've added the missing `:`, used `default:` instead of `case "-":` for the second one, given `parseInt` a radix, and used `0` if for some reason the field contains something that can't be parsed as an int (in which case `parseInt` will return `NaN`, which is falsey, and so the `|| 0` part is used instead; see [*JavaScript's Curiously Powerful OR Operator (||)*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) for details).

But usually when there are only two cases, you'd use `if` or the conditional operator:

`if`:

```
function display(buttonclickedvalue)
{
    var numfield = document.getElementById('numbertxt'),
        num      = parseInt(numfield.value, 10) || 0;
    if (buttonclickedvalue === "+")
    {
        numfield.value = num + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        numfield.value = num - 1;
    }
}
```

Conditional operator:

```
function display(buttonclickedvalue)
{
    var numfield = document.getElementById('numbertxt'),
        num      = parseInt(numfield.value, 10) || 0;
    numfield.value = num + (buttonclickedvalue === "+" ? 1 : -1);
}
```

That last can, of course, be condensed further at the cost of readability:

```
function display(buttonclickedvalue)
{
    var numfield = document.getElementById('numbertxt');
    numfield.value = (parseInt(numfield.value, 10) || 0) + (buttonclickedvalue === "+" ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never set the value somewhere, you change the value but dont do anything with it. I've taken your function and updated it a bit:

```
function display(buttonclickedvalue){
    var currentVal = parseInt(document.getElementById('numbertxt').value, 10); // save current value
    switch (buttonclickedvalue){
        case"+"
            currentVal += 1; // add one. 
        break;
        case"-"
            currentVal -= 1; // subtract one
        break
    }
    // set it back in input (you forgot this:)
    document.getElementById('numbertxt').value = currentVal;
}
```

Also, `case` requires a `:`, and `break` should end with `;`
`currentVal+=1` does the same as `currentVal=currentVal+1`, but imo easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will be help you, this is easy to understand

HTML

```
<input type = text id="numbertxt">
 </br>
 <input type = button value="+" >
 <input type = button value="-" >
```

JS

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    var newnum=eval($('#numbertxt').val());
    if($(this).val()=='+')
    {newnum++;
        $('#numbertxt').val(newnum);
    }else
    {newnum--;
        $('#numbertxt').val(newnum);
    }
     });
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/J6SBQ/)